# hide directories in htaccess without individually

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am hiding folder and sub folder using htaccess. But everytime when new module is added I need to write that module name in htaccess is this possible to tell htaccess to remove module sub folder and show only file as `example.com/abc.php`

below is my code it try to modify it but its not working

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)module/cms/v1/pages/v1.01/cms.php
  RewriteRule ^(.*)cms.php module/cms/v1/pages/v1.01/cms.php$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)module/cms/v1/pages/v1.01/cms_create.php
  RewriteRule ^(.*)cms_create.php module/cms/v1/pages/v1.01/cms_create.php$1 [L]
```

Comment: does /cms/v1/pages/v1.01/  is same with any module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep module name so the URI will be like `site.com/module/abc.php` then redirect it internally to original path,otherwise server will not be able to look for that file with different modules names , Try this if `/cms/v1/pages/v1.01/` is fixed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/cms/v1/pages/v1.01/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1/cms/v1/pages/v1.01/$2 [L]
```

Comment: it means every time i need to repeat this line for different module

Comment: @StackOverflow if module within URI nor repeat , it is only these rules

Comment: No @Mohammed Elhag i want to write just one query for example as all modules are placed in module folder but i want that php pages that are in module sub folder i want not to write separate separate folder name and php file name. Is this possible in htaccess?

Comment: @StackOverflow does module is same ? you said module will be changed right ?

Comment: @StackOverflow if you meant the pages and sub folder inside module will be changed , but the module is fixed , i could change the rules

Comment: new method as i i am trying to use is  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)dashboard_setting/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/*.php`

Comment: i am trying that in dashboard setting /any folder/any folder/any folder/(problem)   how to write here any php file like *.php or anything

Comment: yes module folder name is fixed just files name are also fixed i just change v1 and v2 folder as i add new version folder then htacess will automatically pick that folder

Comment: @StackOverflow you will be able to hide only fixed  folder ,but when uril original path contains v1 and there is same file in v2 how does the server handle that when the URI come without v1 or v2 ?

Comment: @StackOverflow I've already mentioned that in my answer , Thanks